# What is the lifetime of a message-only window?

Tags: excel, vba, windows, winapi, message-queue

I'm creating a message window to receive timer messages in a separate queue from the main Excel Application window. I can then subclass that window without a torrent of irrelevant stuff going through my (slow) VBA message loop.

---

As I understand it, I can use the `hWndParent` parameter along with the `WM_CHILD` style to make a window that is a child of the main window handle. According to the [DestroyWindow docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroywindow):

> If the specified window is a parent or owner window, DestroyWindow
>   automatically destroys the associated child or owned windows when it
>   destroys the parent or owner window.

So I imagine that supplying `Application.hWnd` as the parent would mean that when I close Excel, all the associated windows are removed too.

But [Message-Only Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows) need `HWND_MESSAGE` as the parent, so I'm not sure when/if they'll be cleared up?

---

FWIW, here's the code I'm using to generate/find the window (my program may lose its state so I can't rely on storing the handle in a variable)

```
Public Function getMessageWindow(ByVal windowName As String) As hWnd

    Const className As String = "Static"
    Dim result As hWnd
    result = ApiFindWindow(className, windowName)
    If result.value.address = 0 Then 'not found
        Const HWND_MESSAGE As Long = (-3&)
        result = APiCreateWindowEx(0, className, windowName, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, 0, 0, 0)
    End If
    getMessageWindow = result

End Function
```

Comment: lifetime - until `DestroyWindow` for your window will be not called, or thread, which create window, not exit.

Comment: A window exists until someone destroys it. For a child window, the parent handles that. For a message-only window, you have to destroy it in your own code. Only the thread that creates a window can destroy it, so make sure you destroy your window before the thread that calls `getMessageWindow()` to create it exits

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hmm, funny I'm not getting that behaviour. If I use the code to generate a "Test" window, then close and re-open Excel without explicitly destroying it, ApiFindWindow("Static", "Test") *does not* find the message window still hovering around. Is there nothing associating my new window with the process that created it, so that quitting the Application also destroys the window?

Comment: @Greedo obviously, if you completely exit out of a process, the OS reclaims all resources allocated by that process